# Ignore Two Columns in Update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the code below in a trigger.  I have two columns that are updated by a windows service every 60 minutes in the table I am monitoring.  How can I ignore the two columns from writing to the audit table.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[tMonitors_ChangeTracking] on [dbo].[tMonitors] for insert, update, delete
as

declare @bit int,
@field int,
@maxfield int,
@char int,
@fieldname varchar(128),
@TableName varchar(128),
@PKCols varchar(1000),
@sql varchar(2000), 
@UpdateDate varchar(21),
@UserName varchar(128),
@Type char(1),
@PKFieldSelect varchar(1000),
@PKValueSelect varchar(1000)

select @TableName = 'tMonitors'

-- date and user
select @UserName = system_user ,
@UpdateDate = convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 114)

-- Action
if exists (select * from inserted)
if exists (select * from deleted)
select @Type = 'U'
else
select @Type = 'I'
else
select @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
select * into #ins from inserted
select * into #del from deleted

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
select @PKCols = coalesce(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key fields select for insert
select @PKFieldSelect = coalesce(@PKFieldSelect+'+','') + '''' + COLUMN_NAME + '''' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

select @PKValueSelect = coalesce(@PKValueSelect+'+','') + 'convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME + ',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,    
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c   
where  pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName   
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'   
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME   
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

if @PKCols is null
begin
raiserror('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
return
end

select @field = 0, @maxfield = max(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
while @field < @maxfield
begin
select @field = min(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
select @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
select @bit = power(2,@bit - 1)
select @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
if substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 or @Type in ('I','D')
begin
select @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
select @sql = 'insert tMonitors_Audit (Type, TableName, PrimaryKeyField, PrimaryKeyValue, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UserName)'
select @sql = @sql + ' select ''' + @Type + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @TableName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',' + @PKFieldSelect
select @sql = @sql + ',' + @PKValueSelect
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
select @sql = @sql + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
select @sql = @sql + @PKCols
select @sql = @sql + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
select @sql = @sql + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
select @sql = @sql + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)' 
exec (@sql)
end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

The simple approach, assuming these columns to ignore are *only* updated during this hourly process:

```
IF NOT (UPDATE(col_to_ignore_1) AND UPDATE(col_to_ignore_2))
BEGIN
    ... 
    EXEC(@sql);
END
```

Otherwise you can build a similar list based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, so that the logging only happens when at least one of the other columns is updated, that would end up like this:

```
IF (UPDATE(col_to_audit_1) OR UPDATE(col_to_audit_2) ... )
BEGIN
    ... 
    EXEC(@sql);
END
```

It is not clear from your question whether you want to ignore these two columns always, or only when this hourly process runs. Perhaps another idea is to use a transaction and disable the trigger for this update... it will obviously make the trigger much less complicated.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand I like the exclusionary check...sometimes tables are semi-living in schema and you never know what columns may exist.  The "anti" approach allows you to identify the fields you don't care about and everything else is up for grabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which columns you want to pay attention to by using the "UPDATE(column_name)" syntax, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON tablename
FOR insert, update, delete
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF ( UPDATE(Column1) OR UPDATE(Column2))
BEGIN
  --your sql here
END
```

Other options are available at the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Just note that this ONLY tells you whether or not the column(s) were named in the update statement. If they were named but the values didn't actually change then you will still get back a true value. Also, you could use the COLUMNS_UPDATED function, but I find the method above to be better since it's much clearer than trying to work with bit patterns, etc.

Comment: Tom, the OP already has the logic in the trigger to verify that he is only auditing column values that have actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the complete list of columns changed using `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` and compare it to pre-defined bit patterns.  For tables with many columns, calculating the bit positions can be easier than listing out `UPDATED(every) OR UPDATED(other) OR UPDATED(column)`.

For example, for a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LastPageViewDate datetime NULL,
    GroupID INT NOT NULL
);
```

where you want to ignore updates to `LastPageViewDate`.  You can determine the bitmask via:

```
SELECT name, column_id FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Users')
```

```
name                 column_id
-------------------- -----------
UserID               1
Name                 2
EmailAddress         3
LastPageViewDate     4
GroupID              5
```

The trigger can then check for the little-endian bitmask `0x08` ignoring trailing `0`'s:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_IUD_Users_LogEdit
    ON dbo.Users 
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Ignore page view logging caused by
    -- UPDATE Users SET LastPageViewDate = GETDATE() WHERE UserID = @UserID
    -- Bit 4 == LastPageViewDate
    IF COLUMNS_UPDATED() = 0x08 RETURN;

    -- For forward compatibility, you can ignore unchanged new columns added
    -- by RTRIM'ing the '0's (required since 0x08 != 0x0800)
    --
    --IF REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(max), COLUMNS_UPDATED(), 2), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') IN ('08')
    --  RETURN;

    /* Snipped trigger body */
END
GO
```