# DB2: Ignore Column in Update Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I am trying to write a trigger in DB2, which would fire on an update of all the columns, but one, in a table. I am looking for a way to "ignore" a column in a trigger. What I need is something similar to the following snippet (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101758/ignore-two-columns-in-update-trigger) for SQL Server):

```
IF NOT (UPDATE(column_1)) 
BEGIN
...
END
```

If I understand the DB2 trigger syntax ([link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000931.htm)) correctly, this is not possible in DB2.

Extract:

```
>--+-INSERT--------------------------+--ON--+-table-name-+------>
   +-DELETE--------------------------+      '-view-name--'   
   '-UPDATE--+---------------------+-'                       
             |     .-,-----------. |                         
             |     V             | |                         
             '-OF----column-name-+-'
```

What I ended up doing is just listing all the other columns of the same table (so, opting in instead of opting out):

```
UPDATE OF column_2, column_3, column_4
```

However, I am wondering if there may be a nicer way of doing this. I am on DB2 8.2, but if there is a solution that works in future versions, I would be interested in knowing it, too. Hopefully, we will upgrade some day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness and for anyone else having the same question, I have to mention that the workaround described in the question is indeed the way to go. The DB2 syntax does not let you exclude (ignore) individual columns.